# How to only "take" a segment of a String -- from Index 0 to the white space?

Tags: java, string, methods

If you are given

```
String x = "Hello World!";
```

What string method can you use to save String y as "Hello"? (Only taking the first word from the phrase)

I tried using x.charAt(0), but wasn't sure how to continue.

Comment: What language are you using ?

Comment: This is basic string manipulation - you should take a look at some online examples before posting here. In any case: `String y = x.substring(0, x.indexOf(' ')` in Java - assuming it's java.lang.String

Comment: Java, sorry for not clarifying earlier

Comment: Oh, alright. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how your code should look like :

```
String x = "hello world";

int i = x.indexOf(' ');
String firstWord = x.substring(0, i);
String rest = x.substring(i);
```

`charAt()` only gives the first character and not the first word.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to split it on the spaces, and then select the 0th item:

```
String x = "Hello world!";
String firstWord = x.split(" ")[0];

System.out.println("the first word is " + firstWord);
```